# Recording Audio sound on Internet - C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want build an application on web which records the audio sound through Mic.

If any one can provide some appropriate approach or some links would be helpful.

also if you can suggest some third party control which is free.

The technology for Implementation - ASP.NET , C#

Answer (score 3):

Since you are looking to use C#, check out Silverlight 4 which added microphone support to Silverlight. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/access-web-camera-microphone/) on accessing the microphone in Silverlight 4. [Scratch Audio](http://www.scratchaudio.com) is a great example of a Silverlight support with microphone support.

Answer (score 1):

javascript does not give mic support.  You would have to include another technology to do this.
I know flash supports microsoft input.  It might be the best place to start.  I don't know if silverlight has these features.

The only other things i can think of would be an activeX control for IE, or a standalone application.  Both of these look like much worse approaches

Answer (score 0):

You can use flash to record from microphone and upload it to a server. For the server you can use [Red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/) which is great open source server. 
Here are some examples:

- http://   =>   fms.denniehoopingarner.com/
- http://   =>   mariofalomir.com/blog/?p=101

(Sorry but i can only post 1 hyperlink)